# Unit polarization vectors in the vector potential for the quantization of the free electromagnetic field

Tags: operators, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, polarization

I am studying the quantization of free electromagnetic field using the book "Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics" by Mandel and Wolf ([Mandel&Wolf](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/optical-coherence-and-quantum-optics/F8CB94C70FA64CD3FB60890CA2048168), Chapter 10) and when I started to review the section after find the following expression for the vector potential in terms of a expansion of plane waves (p.468)
$$\boldsymbol{\mathscr{A_k}}(t)=\boldsymbol{\mathscr{c_k}} e^{-iwt}+ \boldsymbol{\mathscr{c^*_{-k}}} e^{iwt}$$
I don't understand why the authors say that it is advantageous to resolve the vector $\boldsymbol{\mathscr{c_k}}$ into two orthogonal components.

My question is why do we have to choose two orthogonal components but no more?

Comment: This is nothing other than the fact that transverse waves can have two polarisations and no more. It has something to do with the masslessness of photons.